# osx bin folder can't be opened

Tags: macos, unix

So I've typed into my console:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

And it says `ln Users/myName/bin/subl: Not a directory`
And I also tried to access it from my finder, and it says: `The folder “bin” can’t be opened because you don’t have permission to see its contents.`
The permission is `-rwxr-xr-x@  1 myName   staff   2.2K Mar  5 02:54 bin`
What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to that directory listing, bin isn't a directory but a regular file (that's what the first `-` in `-rwxr-xr-x@` indicates).  Is it an alias, or something like that?  Also, the `@` in that listing indicates that it has extended attributes and maybe also an ACL (which can override regular permissions) -- try `ls -leO@ ~/bin` for more complete info on it.

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myName  staff  - 2220 Mar  5 02:54 /Users/myName/bin
 com.apple.quarantine   85 `
it says..

Comment: @randomor: com.apple.quarantine is an extended attribute indicating that that file came an untrusted (i.e. internet) source.  Do you have any idea what is this bin thing is and where it came from?  If not, try `file ~/bin` -- that'll look at the contents and try to figure out what kind of file it is.  In any case, I think you'll have to move/rename/delete it, and create a real "bin" folder to replace it.

Comment: thanks. i've run file ~/bin
/Users/myName/bin: POSIX shell script text executable
and i renamed it and created a new folder. but still have no idea what that POSIX thing is. But thanks again, you've solved my problem. i thought it is some important folder that i shouldn't mess with.

Comment: @randomor: Try opening it in a text editor.  I bet it's a shell script that was supposed to be installed IN ~/bin but instead got installed AS ~/bin.  If you can figure out what it is by looking at the text, you can probably rename it appropriately, and put it in ~/bin (after you create that as a folder).